# Issue when I try to execute npm install

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js, npm

when I run the command npm install, it displays this error:

```
[log@server:www]$ npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
npm ERR! Found: vue@2.6.14
npm ERR! node_modules/vue
npm ERR!   dev vue@"^2.5.17" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer vue@"^3.0.0" from vee-validate@4.4.4
npm ERR! node_modules/vee-validate
npm ERR!   vee-validate@"^4.2.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See /root/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-06-09T01_39_40_386Z-debug.log
```

I wonder, how can I fix it? What does it mean?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to install vee-validate version 4.0 in a Vue 2.x application. You can see the compatible version in the [vee-validate repo](https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate#vue-version-support).

How to fix:

**Option 1:**

Install an older version of Vee-validate ([v2](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v2) or [v3](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v3)).

First, you'll need to uninstall the version you currently have installed (I'm assuming you installed vee-validate@next since that's the doc recommendation)

`npm uninstall vee-validate@next`

You can then find the list of versions available with

`npm info vee-validate versions`

Finally, install an older version with

`npm install vee-validate@3.4.9`

Replace the 3.4.9 with whatever version you would like to install - as of the time of writing, 3.4.9 is the latest stable tag

**Option 2:**

Upgrade from Vue 2 to Vue 3 following the [upgrade guide](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/introduction.html).

Note that this is still a work in progress and may have some stability issues and depending on the state of the project I would consider using the above option for the time being.

Answer (score -1):

Step:-1 Make sure node.js is installed on your system. You can check with the command `npm --version` or `node --version`

Step:-2 Clear npm cache. run this command `npm cache clear -f`

Step:-3 Then try to run `npm install`